# SQL: how to fix these errors?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, insert

So I have to loop through a folder of .dat files, extract the data and use INSERT INTO to insert the data into a database.

Here is a pastebin of one of the files to see the data I am working with:

http://pastebin.com/dn4wQjjE

To run the script I just call:

```
populate_database.sh directoryWithDatFiles
```

And the contents of the populate_database.sh script:

```
rm test.sql;
sqlite3 test.sql "CREATE TABLE HotelReviews (HotelID SMALLINT, ReviewID SMALLINT, Author CHAR, Content CHAR, Date CHAR, Readers SMALLINT, HelpfulReviews SMALLINT, Over$

IFS=$'\n'
for file in $1/*;
do
    author=($(grep "<Author>" $file | sed 's/<Author>//g'));
    content=($(grep "<Content>" $file | sed 's/<Content>//g'));
    date=($(grep "<Date>" $file | sed 's/<Date>//g'));
    readers=($(grep "<No. Reader>" $file | sed 's/<No. Reader>//g'));
    helpful=($(grep "<No. Helpful>" $file | sed 's/<No. Helpful>//g'));
    overall=($(grep "<Overall>" $file | sed 's/<Overall>//g'));
    value=($(grep "<Values>" $file | sed 's/<Value>//g'));
    rooms=($(grep "<Room>" $file | sed 's/<Room>//g'));
    location=($(grep "<Location>" $file | sed 's/<Location>//g'));
    cleanliness=($(grep "<Cleanliness>" $file | sed 's/<Cleanliness>//g'));
    receptionarea=($(grep "<Check in / front desk>" $file | sed 's/<Check in \/ front desk>//g'));
    service=($(grep "<Service>" $file | sed 's/<Service>//g'));
    businessservice=($(grep "<Business service>" $file | sed 's/<Business service>//g'));

    length=${#author[@]}
    hotelID="$(echo $file | sed 's/.dat//g' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')";

    for((i = 0; i < length; i++)); do
            sqlite3 test.sql "INSERT INTO HotelReviews VALUES($hotelID, $i, 'author', 'content', 'date', ${readers[i]}, ${helpful[i]}, ${overall[i]}, 9, 10, ${location[i]}, ${cleanliness[i]}, ${receptionarea[i]}, ${service[i]}, ${businessservice[i]})";
    done

done

sqlite3 test.sql "SELECT * FROM HotelReviews;"
```

The problem I have though, is that although much of the script is working, there are still 5 of the 15 columns that I can't get working. I'll just screenshot the errors I get when trying to change the code from:

```
'author' --> ${author[i]}: http://i.imgur.com/zKQLSqT.jpg
'content' --> ${content[i]}: http://i.imgur.com/pnirIo3.jpg
'date' --> ${date[i]}: http://i.imgur.com/urF5DTa.jpg 
9 --> ${value[i]}: http://i.imgur.com/AnBFSWp.jpg
10 --> ${rooms[i]}: same errors as above
```

Anyway, if anyone could help me out on this, I'd be massively grateful.

Cheers!

Comment: Without seeing the commands actually being run those all look like SQL quoting errors. It looks like you need to quote the values in your SQL statement. In other words this is effectively SQL injection.

Comment: This is the command here, isn't it? sqlite3 test.sql "INSERT INTO HotelReviews VALUES($hotelID, $i, 'author', 'content', 'date', ${readers[i]}, ${helpful[i]}, ${overall[i]}, 9, 10, ${location[i]}, ${cleanliness[i]}, ${receptionarea[i]}, ${service[i]}, ${businessservice[i]})";

Comment: And if they are simple quoting errors, is there any chance you can fix them/give me some pointers?

Comment: Yes, but with the variables unexpanded. I meant the expanded version. And yes, I believe that's the problem. You aren't quoting (in the SQL statement itself) any of the values being inserted there. Add `set -x` to the top of the script and see what *exact* SQL statements are being executed and you should see what I mean.

Comment: Wow nice, I didn't know that set -x trick! But here is one of the error lines 1otelReviews VALUES(89130, 18, bora2323
Error: no such column: bora2323 You can see the parser doesn't think the username (bora2323) is in quotes, hence seems to be treating it like referenced column, rather than a string to be inserted into the table. Any idea what the syntax is to get it working then?

Comment: Quote the string in the SQL command itself not just from the shell. If SQL can use single quotes then: `"INSERT ... (..., '$var', ...)' or similar.

Comment: Hmm, I have got it working by just using a standard string by "INSERT...('$var')"; however I'm still unable to get it working for a string array. I was thinking I could just create a temporary string variable and update it with the array value each loop iteration. temp=${author[i]} doesn't work though...do you know how to do it? And sorry for all these questions man :(

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with a lot of XML, I recommend getting to know a SAX parser, such as the one in the Python standard library.  Anyone willing to write a shell script like that has the chops to learn it, and the result will be easier to read and at least have a prayer at being correct.

If you want to stick with regex hacking, turn to **awk**.  Using ">" as your field separator, your script could be simplified with awk lines like

```
/<Author>/ { gsub(/'/, "''", $2); author=$2 }
/<Content>/ { gsub(/'/, "''", $2); content=$2 }
...
END { print author, content, ... }
```

The gsub takes care of your SQL quoting problem by doubling any single quotes in the data.